# NodeJs + Sequelize + Express extra association key addedwhen query-ing

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 tables: Countries and Spots. A country can have many spots and a spot belongs to one country.

I have generated the migrations necessary with sequelize for the 2 tables:

Countries.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Countries', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('NOW()'),
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('NOW()'),
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Countries');
  }
};
```

Spots.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Spots', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      wind: {
        type: Sequelize.FLOAT
      },
      country_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Countries', // name of Target table
          key: 'id', // key in Target table that we're referencing
        },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('NOW()'),
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('NOW()'),
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Spots');
  }
};
```

Everything works ok. I define some routes and some controllers and I try to do Spots.findAll() in my controller

```
const models = require('../models/index')
const Spot = models.Spot

exports.index = async (req, res, next) => {
  const spots = await Spot.findAll()

  res.status(200).json(spots)
}
```

However the query Spot.findAll() tries to ask for CountryId which is a key that obviously doesn't exist and I do not wish for it to exist.

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `name`, `wind`, `country_id`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `CountryId` FROM `Spots` AS `Spot`;
(node:13027) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'CountryId' in 'field list'
```

These are the spot and countries models:

Country.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Country = sequelize.define('Country', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Country.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Country.hasMany(models.Spot)
  };
  return Country;
};
```

Spot.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Spot = sequelize.define('Spot', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    wind: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    country_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  Spot.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Spot.belongsTo(models.Country, {
      foreignKey: 'country_id'
    });
    Spot.hasMany(models.Favorite)
  };
  return Spot;
};
```

I added the foreign_key attribute to belongs_to as I thought that the error surely comes from the associations(I still think it does).

Why does it happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is because you are mixing everything here please follow one convention either camelCase or snack_case.

Write `country_id` as `countryId` and change your table names to lowercase and you will good to go.